# MechanicalSoup tricky html tables

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, python-requests, mechanicalsoup

I'm completely green to MechanicalSoup and webscraping.
I have been working on parsing a html timetable and making it into icalendar (ics) file to get it on mobile. (Which i have succesfully done, yay).

Now to make it work, I downloaded the html of the timetable site once I had selected my timetable. Now I need to use Python to actually navigate to the timetable.

Here is my code so far (I am stuck because the HTML is sooo messy I don't know how to do it, and the documentation for MechanicalSoup is not that large yet):

```
    import argparse
    import mechanicalsoup
    from getpass import getpass
    browser = mechanicalsoup.StatefulBrowser(
        soup_config={'features': 'lxml'},
        raise_on_404=True,
        user_agent='MyBot/0.1: mysite.example.com/bot_info',
     )
    browser.open("http://keaplan.kea.dk/sws/prodE2017/default.aspx")
    browser.select_form(WHAT TO SELECT :D)
```

See the HTML here :( http://keaplan.kea.dk/sws/prodE2017/default.aspx
I want to do the following:

```
    td class=“FilterPanel” #go to the table containing this td
    div id = pFilter  #set value to BYG 
    div id = pObject #set value to BAKINT-2l
    submit (which will redirect to the timetable i need)
```

and download the html from the submitted redirect.

Help is lovingly appreciated!

Comment: "the documentation for MechanicalSoup is not that large yet": it was very true when you posted your question. Less so now: the documentation for MechanicalSoup is not that large yet):

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument of `select_form` is a CSS selector. If you have just one form, then `"form"` can do the trick (the next version of MechanicalSoup will actually have this as default argument). Otherwise, use your browser's developer tools, for example Firefox has Right-Click -> Inspect Element -> Right Click -> Copy -> CSS selector, that can be a good starting point.

In your case, even thought there's a funny layout, there is only one form, so:

```
browser.select_form("form")
```

Unfortunately, the page you are pointing is partly generated with JavaScript (the `select` element you're searching doesn't appear in the soup object obtained by parsing the page). See what MechanicalSoup sees from your page with

```
browser.launch_browser()
```

:-(. You can work around the issue by creating the missing controls yourself with [new_control](http://mechanicalsoup.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mechanicalsoup.html#mechanicalsoup.Form.new_control).